# Pro*C passing a dynamic array to a PL/SQL procedure

Tags: c, oracle, plsql

I want to call a PL/SQL stored procedure from Pro*C which takes an array parameter (table of integer). All the documentation on the Oracle site assumed you are using a static array, or at least one defined in the same procedure as the query.
I want to pass an array to a C function, that can then be sent up to the database. The problem here is that I don't have the size at compile time (or rather it won't be available to the Pro*C preprocessor).
Is there any way to set the length of the array being sent up to the database in code, or do I have to make a new static array and copy my data into it?

An example of the documentation is at [this link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_08arr.htm)

Edit - I found the answer at a non-Oracle site [Oracle Docs](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/maintain/OracleDocs/appdev.816/a76942/pc_07pls.htm#1365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: [Oracle Docs](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/maintain/OracleDocs/appdev.816/a76942/pc_07pls.htm#1365). It's the ARRAYLEN parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [FOR clause](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_08arr.htm#i1775) is you friend here.

Comment: Not quite - I continued randomly typing variants of my question into Google and found the answer. Thanks anyway.